# HTA: Trying to write various input boxes and text areas into a text file and also copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, vbscript, clipboard, copy-paste, hta

first post here, long time reader of the site. I've scoured the Internet as a whole and can't find a solution that works and I've tried many rewrites and can't fix it.

I write HTA files for work. Typically department specific note tools to make their job easier. I have everything working that I need except the copy/paste. I copied the copy/paste section from another tool I wrote and it works, but ignores the \r\n and I've always had issues with that so I'm looking to replace that whole section with something more reliable. So I thought if I could just write to a text file, then copy that text file to the clipboard it would be perfect. Since that would also give them the "Oops, I didn't mean to clear that text" option by just loading up the created text file to see what they hit. I plan to also implement the same "oops" on the clear button, so it will write the file, then clear the input boxes to keep the oops file still there.

To do a quick recap, the Write button works perfect, Clear does too (but needs the write to oops file), and the Copy button needs to be fully rewritten. I'd like to keep it all VBScript if possible since I think my issues thus far are stemming from two code types and my copy/pasting old code into new tools.

One thing to keep in mind is I'm self taught and only make these for work. So don't go super technical on me, I won't understand. If possible please re-write the section(s) needed and let me know why and what's happening in the code so I can grasp the concept and be able to work with it/modify it in the future as I learn and grow.

Code is below:

```
<hta:application
icon="#"
border="thin"
borderStyle="static"
caption="yes"
innerBorder="no"
maximizeButton="no"
minimizeButton="yes"
navigable="no"
scroll="no"
scrollFlat="yes"
singleInstance="yes"
showInTaskbar="yes"
windowState="normal"
contextMenu="no"
version="1.0"
>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Note Tool</TITLE>

<style type='text/css'>
</style>

</head> 

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Function Writer_OnClick()

    UserID = (Document.getElementByID("OB1").Value)
    ContactName = (Document.getElementByID("OB2").Value)
    ExternalNotes = (Document.getElementByID("OB3").Value)
    InternalNotes = (Document.getElementByID("OB4").Value)
    CSKBRef = (Document.getElementByID("OB5").Value)

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("html01.txt",1)
    HTML01 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("html02.txt",1)
    HTML02 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("html03.txt",1)
    HTML03 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("html04.txt",1)
    HTML04 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("html05.txt",1)
    HTML05 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

    Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("poop.html",2,true)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(HTML01)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(UserID)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine "</li><li>Contacts: "
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(ContactName)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(HTML02)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(ExternalNotes)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(HTML03)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(InternalNotes)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(HTML04)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(CSKBRef)
    objFileToWrite.WriteLine(HTML05)
    objFileToWrite.Close
    Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
End Function
</SCRIPT>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub ClearText
       User.Value = "" 
       Contact.Value = "" 
       ExternalNotes.Value = "" 
       InternalNotes.Value = "" 
       CSKB.Value = "" 
    End Sub
</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function RestoreWindowSize()
    {
    window.resizeTo(750, 420);
    }
</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var desc = new Array();
desc['OB1'] = 'User ID';
desc['OB2'] = 'Contact Name';
desc['OB3'] = 'External Notes';
desc['OB4'] = 'Internal Notes';
desc['OB5'] = 'CSKB Topic';

function CopyFields(){
    var copytext = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        copytext += desc[arguments[i]] + ': ' + document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value + '\r\n';
    }
    var tempstore = document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value;
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value = copytext;
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).focus();
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).select();
    document.execCommand('Copy');
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value = tempstore;
}
</script>


<body onload="RestoreWindowSize()">

User ID: <input type="text" name="User" id="OB1"><br>
Contact Name: <input type="text" name="Contact" id="OB2"><br>
External Notes: <textarea rows="5" cols="68" type="text" name="ExternalNotes" id="OB3"></textarea><br>
Internal Notes: <textarea rows="5" cols="68" type="text" name="InternalNotes" id="OB4"></textarea><br>
KB Reference(s): <input type="text" name="CSKB" id="OB5"><br>

<br><br>
<input type="button" onClick="ClearText" value="Clear Me">
<input type="button" name="Copier" value="Copy Me" onClick="CopyFields 'OB1', 'OB2', 'OB3', 'OB4', 'OB5'">
<input type="button" name="Writer" value="Write Me">


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can take a look at this example showing you some useful functions to read from text file and load it in a textarea with HTA ===> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412942/how-to-send-user-input-to-cmd-application-and-get-back-the-output-result?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks Hackoo for the reply. I'm not trying to load into a text area, I'm accepting what the user types into the boxes, writing that to a txt file as well as copying it to the clipboard. It needs to write/copy to clipboard on separate lines for easy reading as well. Plus as I mentioned I'm a beginner, so reading through all of that is gibberish to me and I don't understand what I'm trying to single out for my own purposes, versus all the code needed to run what they wanted to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Dim desc,ID
desc = Array("User ID","Contact Name","External Notes","Internal Notes","CSKB Topic")
ID = Array("OB1","OB2","OB3","OB4","OB5")
Function CopyFields()
Dim copytext,i
    copytext = ""
    For i = LBound(desc) to UBound(desc)
        copytext = copytext & desc(i) & " : " & document.getElementById(ID(i)).value & vbcrlf
    Next
    Msgbox copytext
    document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "text",copytext
End Function
</script>
```

And change the HTML section to :

```
<input type="button" name="Copier" value="Copy Me" onClick="CopyFields()">
```

Comment: That works perfectly, I just remove the msgbox and it goes straight to clipboard. I really appreciate the help Hackoo! I was able to fix my writing to the oops file so all issues have been solved. It now writes to file and copies as well. Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of code. Was there any point to it.

This is how to read the clipboard, writing to it is similar. HTA are IE windows with no security, so you won't need to navigate.

```
Sub Clip
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    'Have to navigate to a local file to put IE into Intranet Zone, else this will generate security dialog asking permission
    ie.Navigate2 FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"  
    txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    ie.quit
    If IsNull(txt) = true then 
        outp.writeline "No text on clipboard"
    else
        outp.writeline txt
    End If
End Sub
```

From Help

> **clipboardData Object Members**
>
> ---
>
> Provides access to predefined clipboard formats for use in editing operations.
>
> **Methods**
>
> clearData , getData , setData