# Running Batch File According to Drop Down List Selection

Tags: windows, forms, vba, hta

I am looking to run one of two batch files based on the user's selection from a drop-down list.

I've managed to create the batch file, but don't know where to start creating the form the user will use.

Here are the requirements:

1. It needs to be something that can be emailed out to users.
2. When they click it they get a Windows form opening which asks them to
   make a selection from a drop down list (Option A or Option B)
3. Once they make their selection and click 'Run', it then runs either Batch
   file A, or Batch file B, depending on which option they selected in
   the drop down list.
4. The batch file will be stored on a server in a
   shared folder they can all access.

Comment: You should make some effort and search and show us what did you tried as code to help you  !

This a hint : You should use a HTA to deal with a drop down list !
You can start with something like that to get some ideas :
[How to send user input to cmd application and get back the output result ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412942/how-to-send-user-input-to-cmd-application-and-get-back-the-output-result?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added this to the original post. I have indeed tried an HTA file with the code below. To test I wanted a msgbox to pop up when making a select (easier than getting the batch file to run), but can't seem to get it to respond at all: Thanks in advance

Comment: <select size="1" name="ImageChooser"> <option value="0">Windows 8</option> <option value="1">Windows 7</option> <option value="2">Loaner</option> If ImageChooser.value = "1" Then MsgBox("Welcome") End If